# How to play each audio element on a page (HTML, JQuery, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

O.k I have a page that has multiple audio elements on it. I am looking for a way to play each one, starting from the first, waiting for it to finish playing and then move on to the next audio element, until the last element. Is there any way possible to accomplish this? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I can't add a code sample because the audio elements are all added dynamically by PHP so it's a empty file before that.

Comment: Maybe a sample of the code you have so far would be great.

Comment: This sounds like a question with no effort expended. Please post some code to demonstrate that you have a starting idea of what you want, we can't write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @liam-schauerman answer, I actually came up with this solution:

```
var index = 0;
var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

function playNext(index) {
    audioElements[index].play();
    $(audioElements[index]).bind("ended", function(){
        index++;
        if(index < audioElements.length){
            playNext(index);          
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#swig").click(function() {
        audioElements[index].play();

        $(audioElements[index]).bind("ended", function(){
             index = index + 1;
             if(index < audioElements.length){
                playNext(index);          
             }                        
        });


    });
});
```

I just blindly coded this. If someone would elaborated and why this works I would appreciate it.

Comment: audioElements here is a sequential jQuery array of each of your HTML5 <audio> tag elements. When the DOM has loaded (document.ready...), a click event is bound to your #swig element. Upon clicking that, the following anonymous function is run.  audioElements[index] is interpreted as audioElements[0] (meaning the first HTML5 audio element in the array). this element is played. Next the 'ended' event (built in to audio elements) is bound to a new anonymous function. Just like click earlier! index is incremented, allowing a different audio element to be referenced.  Hooray recursion!

Comment: @LiamSchauerman No haha I get that the part about the recursion (but thank you). I was wondering why it requires both functions to work properly, even though they essentially do the same thing.

Comment: all you need to call inside your ready block is playNext(index)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by storing each audio element in a queue. Lets say you store each element in an array audioElements.

```
var index = 0;
function playNext(index){
  audioElements[index].play(); //this will play the element
  audioElements[index].on('ended', function(){ //this will bind a function to the "ended" event
    //increment the index to target the next element
    index++;
    if(index < audioElements.length){
      //plays the next song and binds the function to the ended event again until the queue is empty
      playNext(index);          
    }
  }
}
playNext(index);
```