# Play audio tracks randomly without recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have multiple audio elements on a page that are created with javascript based on user selections using checkboxes. When the user clicks a Play button I'd like to play randomly selected audio tracks with a user adjustable delay between tracks, until they click a Stop button. I have this code

```
function loopmusic(){
  if (!looping){
    alert('exiting loopmusic()');
    return 0;
  }
  var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * audioElements.length);
  //audioElements[index].volume=0.5;    
  $(audioElements[index]).bind("ended", function(){
    audioElements[index].pause()
    loopmusic()    
  });  
  setTimeout(audioElements[index].play(), delayms);
}
```

That code was adapted from what I read here:
[How to play each audio element on a page (HTML, JQuery, Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995654/how-to-play-each-audio-element-on-a-page-html-jquery-javascript)

Right now the event listener doesn't appear to be acting the way I expected, there is no delay between tracks, and multiple tracks play at the same time. I would like any pointers on how to fix this, and if I could do it without recursion that would be preferable. This may run for some time and I would like to avoid it eating a lot of memory.

Comment: Why do you call `.pause()` after track has completed? Where is `delayms` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to post a ton of code, yes the looping global variable and the delayms global variable are defined before the loopmusic() function is called. 
I called .pause() because I saw it in another posting, and thought it would stop the multiple tracks playing at once, but I have no clue what's going on at this point, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `js` at post? That is, removing `()` at `.play()` at `setTimeout`? which invokes `.play()` immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now the event listener doesn't appear to be acting the way I
>   expected, there is no delay between tracks, and multiple tracks play
>   at the same time.

You are invoking `.play()` instead of referencing `.play`; try removing `()` following `.play()` at `setTimeout` call. Also, calling `.pause()` at `ended` event does not appear to be necessary. Not certain where `delayms` is defined?

```
setTimeout(audioElements[index].play, delayms);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't include more code, delayms is defined before the function loopmusic() is called, it is between 1000 and 6000.
 I tried this approach and the tracks don't play: 

    setTimeout(audioElements[index].play, delayms);;

Also is there a way I can avoid recursion?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to perform actions without recursion. You can use `.queue()`. _"I tried this approach and the tracks don't play:"_ Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle here but I don't have online tracks, I'll try to find online one second tracks so this can be tested quickly. 
        https://jsfiddle.net/mscir/0qst1sLw/6/

Comment: Try wikipedia or creative commons. Random selection and playing of audio could probably be simplified

Comment: Thanks, I'd mark you up but I don't have enough reputation pts yet, sorry. .

Comment: I found a way to keep this simple, I have a page with a checkbox for each sound track, and radio buttons for allowing repeats or not, and a button that writes a page with an HTML5 sound player in a new window (w/javascript), This approach allowed me to create a randomly ordered playlist with any number of elements. Right now I write 1,000 song entries in the playlist array and the popup window still opens quickly! I can post the code on jsfiddle if anyone is interested in this approach. 
http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio